# JavaScript - difference between conditions and if/else?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a major difference between this:

```
var status = (age >= 18) ? "adult" : "minor";
```

and this?

```
var status;

if (age >= 18)
    status = "adult";
else
    status = "minor";
```

Comment: The first one is secure, the second one just screams for non-obvious errors. Please always use `{}` especially in JavaScript, where automatic semicolon insertion can screw you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a difference as far as performance goes. Some browsers use or used to be slower with the `if()` compared to the `? :`. With the current way of browsers pre-compiling JavaScript-code this might not be an issue anymore. If you plan to do time critical stuff compatible with older browsers, this might be something to think about, though.

However, as far as the logic of the code is concerned, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

To add my two cents, this (?:) is called a ternary operator.  Wikipedia has a good article on the subject.  Pretty much supported in every high level language.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: It's called a conditional operator.

Comment: Don;t use Wikipedia as an authoritative source. Use Wikipedia to find the authoritative source (in this case a Javascript reference and use that).

Comment: It's the most well known ternary operator, that's all. By the way, that's exactly what wikipedia says.